# appended values in html not appearing where I expect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have a table that initially shows

1. headers,
2. a total price variable,
3. buttons across the bottom.

I put a template after 1.headers expecting the appended values to show up before the total price variable and the buttons, but they are appended to the bottom. What am I missing in order to insert the new values where I put the template for them. I want them to show up before

```
  <td><p id="totalPrice" align="right"> Price </p></td>
```

I have a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SteveRobertson/kGKmE/) showing my problem.

Thank you for any suggestions

Comment: Can you narrow down the code a bit, as well as post it in the actual question?  There appears to be a lot of unnecessary code just to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Invalid HTML. Please fix that first. `<table><tr>...</tr><form><tr>...</tr></table></form>` ???

Comment: @David just updated, there was not much to take out, although it looks like I have some responses down there to check out

Comment: @squint it is ejs not html, is that what you are referring to or is there something else?

Comment: @Four_lo: What's ejs? I'm talking about your HTML markup. Your tags are not balanced correctly, and you have invalid placement of some elements.

Comment: @squint ejs is embedded javascript templates, it is for doing client side templates, but I actually do not think I apply it anywhere there so it is basically html, but I did receive an answer for my question. Where is there invalid placement though?

Comment: @Four_lo: The `form` opening/closing tags are unbalanced. You need to open and close within the same parent. Also, it's not valid for a `form` to be the child of a `table`, or for a `<tr>` to be the child of a `form`. What's going to happen when you use invalid markup is that the browser is going to rearrange things as best it can guess, and things will eventually end up not working as you expect.

Comment: @squint Oh ok. I was not aware of this. I really appreciate it. Probably saved me a world of confusion down the line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could give the `<tr>` with the total price a class so that you can insert it before.

```
<tr class="total">
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td><p id="totalPrice" align="right"> Price </p></td>
</tr>
```

And then:

```
template(newRow, quoteItem)
    .insertBefore($('#quote .total'))
    .fadeIn();
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/kGKmE/8/)

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
    template(newRow, quoteItem)
    .insertAfter('#quote tr.template')
    .fadeIn();
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eqGGJ/)

Comment: If you do this, the next inserted row would be before the last :)

Comment: thank you for helping. I think I may need it to be at the end.

Answer (score -1):

Your table structure is totally messed up, try and remove the form from the table and wrap the tyble body and footer, this should also help with your real problem.